# Inserting files (pdf etc..) into a database using asp.net c#

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, database, visual-studio

I want to create a document matrix that allows users to upload files into a web based database.
I am getting errors regrading to the access the file path. 
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not find file 'C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\auto.docx'.'

The data type in the database is Varbinary(MAX).
Also there is no issue with the connection to the database.

Here is the button event for uploading the file.

```
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //get file path from file upload button 
         String filepath=    System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);

        //Converts file(.txt pdf etc..) into byte[]
        byte[] filedata = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filepath);

       //Insert file into database
        cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO tbl_test (Name)" +
                                    " Values ('" + TextBox1.Text + "','" + filedata + "')";
        cmd.Connection = mycon;
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        mycon.Close();
    }
```

Comment: Just to add. this is local on my machine for now. I was thinking there might be security issues with accesses files.

Comment: `System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);` makes no sense. The file isn't on the file system. It is in memory.

Comment: Have a read of https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httppostedfile.inputstream(v=vs.110).aspx .

Comment: if that Path is wrong, what is the correct way

Comment: but i'm using the fileupload button. which allows me to browse and select a file. Surly by me selecting the file, the path can be found. Therefore a path can be generated.

Comment: I don't know how else to say it but your understanding of how web servers work is incorrect. It has no knowledge of your network. It doesn't care. It is simply a collection of bytes that were uploaded from a web browser and are now stored in the web server's memory. You might wish that wasn't the case, but it is indeed how the web works.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Are you by any chance using Windows 10?

If so, is that folder a 'read-only' folder? I had this issue last year and could check for you to confirm how I fixed it.

```
if (FileUpload1.PostedFile != null)
    {
        filePath = FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName; // gets the file name with path.
    }
```

Comment: Yes im on windows 10. Thank you

Comment: It is irrelevant. The file isn't on the file system.